# Integer.parseInt() problems

Tags: java

My code is not giving me the right output. It reads numbers from a text file, converts them to an integer value and performs some multiplication on them. But the the products that method `findProduct()` gives me are wrong, so I think I am using the `Integer.parseInt()` method incorrectly.

I guess what is throwing me off is that It is trying to tell me the product of 96086x67017=2144428166, When checking on my calculator it is around 643939395462.

```
/*
 * 
 * Find the greatest product of five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit number.

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

this text file is in Project_8.txt
*/


import java.io.*;
// Import the scanner class that is used for reading the text file
import java.util.*;


public class Project_8 {

// Data members================================
// Object used to read the text file
private Scanner scanner;



// Public Methods==============================
// Points the scaaner object in the direction of the text file. Outputs an error if file is not found
public void openFile(){

    try{
        // Note the whole file's path is required
        scanner = new Scanner(new File("/Users/nicolematthews/Desktop/Tim/Java WORKSPACE/Project_Euler/src/Project_8.txt"));

    }catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println("Could not find the File. Check file's address");

    }
}



public String readFile(){

    // Instantiating the scanner for user input ruins its application for reading files
    //scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Method looks the text file and adds each line of the text to the String sequence.
    // the Method returns sequence

        String sequence = "";

        // While the scanner has more data to read
        while(scanner.hasNext()){

            sequence = sequence + scanner.next();

        }

    return sequence;
}





// This method simply closes the scanner object
public void closeFile(){

    scanner.close();
}









public int findProduct(String sequence){


    int highestProduct = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < ( sequence.length() - 10 ); i++){

        // Extract adjacent 5 digit strings which will be converted to integers
        String num1 = sequence.substring(i, i + 5);

        String num2 = sequence.substring(i + 5, i + 10);

        if( Integer.parseInt(num1)*Integer.parseInt(num2) > highestProduct ){

            highestProduct = Integer.parseInt(num1)*Integer.parseInt(num2);

            System.out.println(num1);
            System.out.println(num2);
            System.out.println(highestProduct);
            System.out.println("\n");

        }

    }

    return highestProduct;

}



// Main Method =========================================
public static void main(String args[] ) throws IOException{



    Project_8 object = new Project_8();

    object.openFile();

    String Sequence = object.readFile();

    System.out.println(Sequence);


    System.out.printf("%d Is the highest product of five consecutive \n" +
            "digits in the 1000-digit number.", object.findProduct(Sequence));



    // Finally, close the file when we are done with it.
            object.closeFile();
    /* Find the greatest product of five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit number


    System.out.println(Sequence);

*/      





}
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide an example of the input you give it, the output you actually get, and the output that you expected?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your sequence index `i` is only advancing by 1 for each iteration, `i++`, but you consume **10** characters on each iteration. You've indicated that this is your intent.

You'll overflow a java `int` with *many* of the 5-digit sub-sequences from your data. For instance, your second product will be `31671 * 76531 = 2423813301`. This is larget than `Integer.MAX_INT`: *2^31 - 1*.

Changing the `findProduct` method to use `long` and `Long.parseLong()` will fix this.

Comment: My intention was to only increment by one and to account for all possible 5 digit numbers. But i like the idea of adding more Exception Handling

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is caused by the number extractor part of the code, are all the numbers exactly 5 characters long? If that is not the case, your code won't work well because your code expects it to be 5 characters long. If there are spaces inside, `Integer.parseInt()` will complain unless you call `trim` on it, which you have not done.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement does too much all at once:

```
if( Integer.parseInt(num1)*Integer.parseInt(num2) > highestProduct ){
```

You should break this up to assign each int value to a separate variable. That way you can print these values to see if they are the correct one. Also, it will allow you to remove the rpeated calls to Integer.parseInt() in the next line.